# Is this a real answer?

Tags: support, declined-flags, not-an-answer, specific-answer

Regarding this answer:

[How to play .mov file in Android devices using default player?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13677599/how-to-play-mov-file-in-android-devices-using-default-player/16667914#16667914)

> .MOV not supported in android.

I've flagged it as NAA, because it basically reiterates that .mov files are not supported on an android phone; after all, the question says this:

> when I tried to play in any Android devices it is not supporting in their default player.

The flag was declined. The description of this particular flag is that although it's posted as an answer, it makes no attempt at answering the question, which is "how to play an .mov video on android devices".

I thought it was a clear case. Did I miss something obvious here?

---

[Screenshot of question for <10k users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MryCK.png)

Comment: "No" can sometimes be an answer to "how-to" questions. It simply means you cannot do that somehow. The answer may be technically inaccurate or insufficient, but it is still an answer.

Comment: Low quality != not an answer.

Comment: If you're asking "how can I do X?" and it turns out that it is completely impossible, an answer stating "you can't do X" would be perfectly fine.

Comment: It is an answer saying the same thing as the already accepted answer, but without citing any sources or references. It's a poor answer for loads of reasons.

Comment: @Bart: Of course, the question is asking "I know I can't do X, but how do I do it?" in a way.

Comment: The answer is now deleted. For those with <10K The complete text of it was `".MOV not supported in android."`

Comment: @MartinSmith: added screenshot

Comment: @Manishearth Fair enough, let's make it "you really really can't do X". ;)

Comment: @Manishearth - Just out of curiosity what does the "punch" link do?

Comment: @MartinSmith: http://stackapps.com/questions/3802/punch-a-user-button

Comment: @Mat That page doesn't say what will happen if you "punch" a user.

Comment: @Antony: no, it's even better than that. It lets you do it.

Answer (score 5):

> See also: [Will we allow "no" and "not currently possible" answers? What to do about them?](https://windowsphone.meta.stackexchange.com/q/40/378)

It's an answer. It's a short one (and could be longer as demonstrated by the accepted answer), but "No, you can't" is still a valid answer. It can be downvoted, that's all.

However, you're right that it is reiterating what the question says. In this case, the question has answered itself, and is really Not A Real Question. In this case it's a bit iffy, because there is the chance of some neat trick (changing the extension, etc) that would still answer the question. But that seems like groping for straws here, the essence of the question is "I know that X is not possible, but how can I do it?".

Comment: I guess the problem here was that the answer isn't technically inaccurate, nor altogether wrong ... and yet it doesn't answer the question, which is obvious and yet not truly self-answering either; and mp4 (afaik) is supported on both platforms.